# How to align numbers in a table made of ASCII characters

Tags: c, printf

I want to print a string of `int double double double double double double` in a table made of ASCII characters. What ways are there to keep the values aligned with the table headers and ensure they don't 'overflow'?

My table header looks something like this:

```
+---------+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
 NrCamere | smin   smax   smed |  pmin      pmax      pmed
+---------+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
printf("%10f %10f\n", double_val0, double_val1);
```

That would print the two doubles with 10 characters width max.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the columns fixed width so the next value in the row doesn't underflow?

Comment: The above statement will also keep the columns fixed at 10 chars width

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a maximum string width like this:

```
printf("%*d", field_width, number);
```

The * is replaced with the supplied int to provide the ability to dynamically specify the field width.